# Reverse for 'posts' with keyword arguments '{'id': 106}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['posts/$']

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

I am building a BlogApp AND Everything is working fine BUT when i  `return redirect('mains:posts',id=post_id)`. It is showing me :-

> Reverse for 'posts' with keyword arguments '{'id': 106}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['posts/$']
> ,
> views.py

```
    def post_like_dislike(request, post_id):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
        # Like
        if request.GET.get('submit') == 'like':
            if request.user in post.dislikes.all():
                post.dislikes.remove(request.user)
                post.likes.add(request.user)
                return JsonResponse()
            elif request.user in post.likes.all():
                post.likes.remove(request.user)
                return redirect('mains:posts',id=post_id)
            else:
                post.likes.add(request.user)
                return JsonResponse({'action': 'like_only'})
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Something went wrong')
            return redirect('mains:posts',id=post_id)

 The Error is is at this Line -----------------^
```

detail.html

```
                <form method="GET" class="likeForm d-inline" action="{% url 'mains:post_like_dislike' data.id %}"
                    data-pk="{{ data.id }}">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i>
                        <span id="id_likes{{data.id}}">
                            {% if user in data.likes.all %}
                            {{data.likes.count}}</p>
                            {% else %}
                            {{data.likes.count}}</p>
                            {% endif %}
                        </span><form><button name='submit' type='submit' value="like"> Like </button></form>
                    </button>
                </form>
```

**ERROR**

When i click on Like button, it is showing `Reverse for 'posts' with keyword arguments '{'id': 106}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['posts/$']`.

Any help would be Appreciated.

Thank You in Advance

Comment: Add your url.py please

Comment: Do you have a URL called `posts` and another called `post`? Looks like the two are getting confused here and you're passing the ID which would work for `post` to the `posts` page.

Comment: I have only posts in views,urls.

Comment: @GaëtanGR, I HAVE UPLOADED

Answer (score 2):

So you're using `redirect('mains:posts',id=post_id)`

But in the `mains` application the `posts` URL doesn't take any parameters.

> Reverse for 'posts' with keyword arguments '{'id': 106}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['posts/$']

This error gives you a clue, because it shows you the URL it tried which is `posts/$`

Therefore `redirect('mains:posts')` would match this attempted URL because it doesn't provide any arguments and the path/url doesn't expect any.

From the URL you have included;

`path('post_like_dislike/<int:post_id>/',views.post_like_dislike, name='post_like_dislike'),`

This is a URL which does expect a parameter of a `Post` object ID. So this would be redirected to with something like;

`redirect('mains:post_like_dislike', post_id=post_id)`

Comment: So you Mean, I should use :- `return redirect('mains:post_like_dislike',id=post_id)` instead of return redirect('mains:posts,id=post_id)

Comment: No, because you might not want to redirect to that view. It's up to you what you use. I'm just trying to explain that by including `,id=post_id` in the `redirect` you're causing the error because the `posts` URL doesn't take any parameters

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR YOUR HELP. I appreciate it

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65814289/return-jsonresponse-is-printing-its-values-after-click) is the main reason of uploading the question you answered. Please help

Comment: So this isn't the answer to this question anymore?

Comment: I have solved both the Errors. AND thank you very much for your Effort. Thank you very much for spend your Quality time to answer my Question.

Comment: Congratulations , You reached 9K reputation.